# Drawing a Cube with Tikz/PgfPlots Looks Stretched along X-Axis

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I'm trying to draw a cubic structure (fcc crystal structure) with Tikz. I'm using pgfplots' `axis cs` function for the 3D projection. But the result looks like a rectangle stretched along the x axis.

Here is the result

[image: pdf]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vector/.style={thick,black,>=stealth,->},
  atom/.style={blue}
  ]
  \begin{axis}[
    axis lines=none,
    xmin=-0.1,
    xmax=1.1,
    ymin=-0.1,
    ymax=1.1,
    zmin=-0.1,
    zmax=1.1,
    xtick=\empty,
    ytick=\empty,
    ztick=\empty
    ]
    \coordinate (A0) at (axis cs:0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A1) at (axis cs:1,0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (axis cs:0,1,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (axis cs:0,0,1);

    \coordinate (A4) at (axis cs:1,1,0);
    \coordinate (A5) at (axis cs:1,0,1);
    \coordinate (A6) at (axis cs:0,1,1);
    \coordinate (A7) at (axis cs:1,1,1);

    \coordinate (A8) at (axis cs:0.5,0.5,0);
    \coordinate (A9) at (axis cs:0.5,0,0.5);
    \coordinate (A10) at (axis cs:0,0.5,0.5);

    \coordinate (A11) at (axis cs:0.5,0.5,1);
    \coordinate (A12) at (axis cs:0.5,1,0.5);
    \coordinate (A13) at (axis cs:1,0.5,0.5);

    \draw[black!25] (A0) -- (A8) -- (A4);
    \draw[black!25] (A4) -- (A12) -- (A6);
    \draw[black!25] (A0) -- (A10) -- (A6);
    \draw[black!25] (A1) -- (A8) -- (A2);
    \draw[black!25] (A2) -- (A10) -- (A3);
    \draw[black!25] (A7) -- (A12) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A1) -- (A13) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A11) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A13) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A11) -- (A5);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A9) -- (A0);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A1);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A3);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A3);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A5);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A6);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
    \draw[black] (A7) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A1) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A2) -- (A4);
    \fill[blue] (A8) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A8);
    \fill[blue] (A10) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A10);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A9) -- (A1);
    \fill[atom] (A1) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A2) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A3) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A4) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A5) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A6) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A7) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A9) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A11) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A12) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A13) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A9);
    \fill[blue] (A0) circle (5pt);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

What causes the stretching? How can I change it into a perfect cube?

Solution: Setting `axis equal=true`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: Setting `axis equal=true` in the axis option fixes the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've rechecked the pgfplots manual and setting `axis equal=true` in the axis options fixes the issue.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use `pgfplots`, only `(x,y,z)` coordinates. The relation between them can be fixed in `tikzpicture` options. Next figure uses `x=2cm,y=2cm,z=1cm`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  vector/.style={thick,black,>=stealth,->},
  atom/.style={blue}, x=2cm,y=2cm,z=1cm
  ]
    \coordinate (A0) at (0,0,0);
    \coordinate (A1) at (1,0,0);
    \coordinate (A2) at (0,1,0);
    \coordinate (A3) at (0,0,1);

    \coordinate (A4) at (1,1,0);
    \coordinate (A5) at (1,0,1);
    \coordinate (A6) at (0,1,1);
    \coordinate (A7) at (1,1,1);

    \coordinate (A8) at (0.5,0.5,0);
    \coordinate (A9) at (0.5,0,0.5);
    \coordinate (A10) at (0,0.5,0.5);

    \coordinate (A11) at (0.5,0.5,1);
    \coordinate (A12) at (0.5,1,0.5);
    \coordinate (A13) at (1,0.5,0.5);

    \draw[black!25] (A0) -- (A8) -- (A4);
    \draw[black!25] (A4) -- (A12) -- (A6);
    \draw[black!25] (A0) -- (A10) -- (A6);
    \draw[black!25] (A1) -- (A8) -- (A2);
    \draw[black!25] (A2) -- (A10) -- (A3);
    \draw[black!25] (A7) -- (A12) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A1) -- (A13) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A11) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A13) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A11) -- (A5);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A9) -- (A0);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A1);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A3);
    \draw[black] (A0) -- (A3);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A5);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A6);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A2);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A1);
    \draw[black] (A7) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A5) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A1) -- (A4);
    \draw[black] (A6) -- (A7);
    \draw[black] (A2) -- (A4);
    \fill[blue] (A8) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A8);
    \fill[blue] (A10) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A10);
    \draw[black] (A3) -- (A9) -- (A1);
    \fill[atom] (A1) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A2) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A3) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A4) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A5) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A6) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A7) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A9) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A11) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A12) circle (5pt);
    \fill[atom] (A13) circle (5pt);
    \draw[vector] (A0) -- (A9);
    \fill[blue] (A0) circle (5pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The xyz coordinates have the disadvantage though that in the resulting angle some atoms cover each other. I guess this could be changed by further adjusments. But I've just learned that setting `axis equal=true` fixes my issue.